# Is the following sentence correct? 'The time when the church dates back to is the 13th.' *

Tags: phrasal-verbs

The question is about the relative pronoun 'when' used instead of 'in which', 'at which', 'on which', 'from which', 'to which', etc.

> The church dates back to the 13th century.

Putting emphasis on the time…

> The time to which the church dates back is the 13th century. (formal)
>
> The time which the church dates back is the 13th century.
>
> The time [relative pronoun left out] the church dates back to is the 13th century.

Are the following relative clauses correct?

> ? 1) The time when the church dates is the 13th century.
>
> ? 2) The time when the church dates back is the 13th century.
>
> ? 3) The time when the church dates back to is the 13th century.

Comment: **The church dates back to the 13th Century** sounds more fluent.

Comment: Rather than start with /The time/ you can use: The church ***does*** date back to the 13th century. That emphasizes the time.

Comment: @Lambie **Does** seems to emphasise the truth of the statement rather than the time.

Comment: Well, the truth of the statement for me ***is*** the time.

Comment: I agree with @Bladorthin. "The church dates back to the 13th Century" is colloquial, well-formed, and gets the job done in relatively few words. Why use more words than are necessary? If you really want to strip the sentence to the bone, you could say "The church is 13th Century."

Comment: If I had to phrase it beginning with "the time", I would say "The time to which the church dates is the 13th century."  I feel like *back* is nonfluent in that usage, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: You should use *the time which*. *The time when* is redundant, so there's no reason to prefer *when* to *which*.  And the grammar of the sentence makes *when* awkward.

Comment: My question is NOT AT ALL about ways of emphasising the time element in the sentence. It is simply, as mentioned in the opening sentence of the question, about whether or not you can always replace 'in which', 'at which', 'to which', 'from which', etc., by 'when', when making a relative clause about time. Can 'The century (which/that) the church dates back to is the 13th.' be replaced by 'The century when the church dates back to is the 13th.', which sounds very awkward to me... ?

Answer (score 2):

> The church dates back to the 13th century.

As others have said, this is the best way to indicate the age of the church.  However, your question asks specifically about how to start the sentence with *the time* as the subject.  Of your three examples, this one is grammatical:

> The time [when the church dates back to] is the 13th century.

As stangdon mentions in his comment, you can rephrase this as follows:

> The time [to which the church dates] is the 13th century.

As Peter Shor mentions in his comment, you may also use "which" in place of "when":

> The time [which the church dates back to] is the 13th century.

If you are going to use "time" -- meaning a "particular moment" -- you must include "dates back to" or "dates to".  Otherwise if you change the subject to the "age" or the "duration" you can use other phrases:

> The church has been standing *since* the 13th century
>
> How long has the church been standing?
>
> The *length of time* [the church has been standing] is [since the 13th century].

It's a clumsy sentence -- "around 800 years" sounds better than "since the 13th century" -- but it is grammatical.  Related example:

> The church is 800 years old
>
> How old is the church?
>
> The *age* of the church is 800 years.

Comment: "The time when the church dates back to is the 13th century", "The length of time the church has been standing is since the 13th century": These are both flat-out wrong.

Comment: @TonyK unconstructive and rude comments are a waste of everyone's time.  If you think they're "wrong" then you should explain why.   In any case please read my answer and recognize the difference between "inelegant" and "ungrammatical".

Comment: @snailplane: Just as a matter of interest, do you believe that a native English speaker might utter these sentences? (Andrew does claim to be a native English speaker.)

Comment: @TonyK - I don’t think Andrew is saying this is how native speakers talk. Andrew's answer plainly states: _Your question asks specifically about how to start the sentence with_ ‘the time’ _as the subject._ These sentences need to be analyzed in that context.

Answer (score 1):

As BladorthinTheGrey says **The church dates back to the 13th century** sounds more fluent.

I appreciate you are trying to emphasis "the time" but it's just completely redundant in this sentence (there is no other way to "date back" except in time). If you absolutely must include time in some form, then I suppose you could reasonably say:

**The church dates back to the time of the 13th century**

but unfortunately this fails to include the "when" that you're question is focused on.